# how to impliment call recording using Agora Io with react native. Is it possible?

Tags: react-native, agora.io, call-recording

1.RtcEngine.startAudioRecordingWithConfig({filePath: '/storage/emulated/0/'});
2.RtcEngine.stopAudioRecording();

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [startAudioRecording](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/react_native/classes/rtcengine.html#startaudiorecording) method to record the audio of the call using the React Native SDK. If you want to record video, you can use [cloud recording](https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/landing-page?platform=RESTful).